# UINavigationController with UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I know that Apple don t "aprove" the "UiSplitViewController" to don´t be the main root from an app.

However, I need to create an app that have a "UINavigationControler", which have in one of his view´s an UiSplitViewController.
Any idea how I can do that correctly, I am stuck.

By the way, my RootViewController is TabBarController, which in one of his view have that "UINavigationController".

Any idea will help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hope to get your app approved for distribution on the App Store, you can't do this.

If you are using Enterprise distribution, or just messing around, you can probably get this to work:

1. Add a new view to your project (NewView)
2. Duplicate the view hierarchy from a SplitViewController view into NewView
3. Push NewView onto your navigation controller stack like normal

You won't be able to find much help on getting this to work though, because it is wasted effort (as Apple won't allow it).